# Duvida como deixar um atributo unico - JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jpa-2.0

estou criando um entidade, e possuo um campo CPF e este campo que que seja unico, como mapear esse campo CPF?

Minha entidade.

```
@Entity
```

public class Cliente {

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long codigo;
private String nome;
private String cpf;
private String telefoneFixo;
private String telefoneCelular;
```

Comment: Isso pode ajudá-lo http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/pt-br/SSRTLW_8.0.4/org.eclipse.jpt.doc.user/getting_started004.htm

Answer (score 2):

Você pode fazer a nível de classe dentro da anotação `@Table`, segue um exemplo:

```
@Entity
@Table(uniqueConstraints={@UniqueConstraint(columnNames={"cpf"})})
public class Entidade{

    @Column
    public String cpf;
}
```

Fonte: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/UniqueConstraint.html

Comment: obrigado! tentar aqui....

Comment: tentei fazer desta forma, e permitiu salvar duplicado, agora fiz  @Column(unique=true) em cima do campo cpf consegui.

@Table(uniqueConstraints={@UniqueConstraint(columnNames={"cpf"})})

Comment: Vou fazer alguns teste e complemento minha resposta. Obrigado pelo feedback

Answer (score 2):

Experimente:

```
@Column(unique=true)
private String cpf;
```

**EDIT**

A sugestão enviada pelo adelmo00 é uma melhor prática do que aquela que sugeri pois permite a definição de um ou mais campos como únicos. Se tiver a certeza que só o campo cpf necessita de ser único não há problema em utilizar a minha sugestão, no entanto, se posteriormente quiser definir mais atributos como únicos, para não estar a escrever    @Column(unique=true) para cada campo, recomendo usar a sugestão do adelmo00.

Comment: valeu amigo pela ajuda.